# Find case-insensitive word matches in a line

Tags: ruby, regex

I need to look for all occurrences of a word in a line, but the search must be case insensitive. What else do I need to add to my regular expression?

```
arr = line.scan(/\s+#{word}\s+/)
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need modifier `/i`

```
arr = line.scan(/\b#{word}\b/i)
```

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_regular_expressions.htm

And better to use `\b` for word boundaries, because the second `\s+` in your regex *eats* spaces, which may be used for the first `\s+` of another matched word; also your regex fails on the beginning and the end of line:

```
> "asd asd asd asd".scan /\s+asd\s+/
=> [" asd "]
> "asd asd asd asd".scan /\basd\b/
=> ["asd", "asd", "asd", "asd"]
```

Comment: wow that was easy lol, I need to wait 7 minutes to accept your answer. Thanks.