# How can I replace every case-sensitive instance of a word in a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm working on an exercise that asks me to do the following:

*Given a string, replace every instance of sad to happy.  You must consider if sad is capitalized, uppercase, etc. .*

Ok, well that's easy enough when 'sad' is not capitalized:

```
def sub_sad_for_happy(string)
  string.gsub('sad', 'happy')
end

sad_string = "Pierrot is sad."

sub_sad_for_happy(sad_string) # => "Pierrot is happy."
```

But what if sad is capitalized?

Comment: What happens with `"SAD"`, `"sAd"`, etc?

Comment: If "Sad", do you want "happy" or "Happy"?

Comment: extra points for replacing `:-(` with `:-)`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes.  I should have clarified that.  Also, if it was sAd (as sawa pointed out) it would need to return hAppy.

Comment: @Stefan - that is an interesting challenge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find case-insensitive word matches in a line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612128/find-case-insensitive-word-matches-in-a-line)

Comment: I still don't have the answer to my question. You added, "You must consider if sad is capitalized, uppercase, etc.". That does not clarify at all. I read "etc." as "if you know what I mean". No, we do not know what you mean. You need to be concise, precise and complete with your words, not just for SO, but for success in your chosen profession generally.

Comment: User clarified the question and we have an answer, **reopen**.

Answer (score 4):

Its very easy to handle ignore case in ruby regex using `/i` modifier. And also notice I have placed the regex inside `//`

```
string.gsub(/sad/i, 'happy')
```

Now, if you want to keep only the `s` to be both cases, then use character class. [sS] means either `s` or `S`

```
string.gsub(/[sS]ad/, 'happy')
```

Comment: will that replace `Sad` with `Happy`? ie. caps replaced with caps?

Comment: it will only change `Sad` or `sad` into `happy`. If you want `Happy` then have to change replacement word.

Comment: @deanosaur If that is a requirement, then write that in the question. Your question is unclear on this point anyway.

Comment: @deanosaur you can pass a hash to gsub: `string.gsub(/[sS]ad/, 'sad' => 'happy', 'Sad' => 'Happy')`

Comment: @Stefan Just learned it. I didn't know we can pass hash to gsub. Thanks for this added info.

Comment: @estebanrules that case try with the first example I have provided.

Comment: @Stefan - that works.  Thank you.  I also didn't know you could pass a hash to gsub.

Comment: I modified the question for clarification.

Comment: Stefan has officially answered my question.  I'm not sure how I mark my question as answered.

Comment: I also don't understand why this question is still on hold, as a.) I re-worded the question and b.) the question was answered.