# Is there any case-insensitive standard analogue of the String#start_with function in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Is there any case-insensitive standard analogue of the `String#start_with?` function in Ruby or should I write it by myself?

Comment: Did you look at the `i` modifier yet?

Comment: You may want to look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4612128/find-case-insensitive-word-matches-in-a-line).

Comment: Use this method [1](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-match) or [2](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/String.html#method-i-3D-7E). It supports *RegEx*, thus  you can use `i`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one. A simple implementation:

```
class String
  def start_with_ignore_case?(prefix)
    downcase.start_with?(prefix.downcase)
  end
end
```

Or, using a Regexp:

```
class String
  def start_with_ignore_case?(prefix)
    !!(/\A#{Regexp.escape prefix}/i =~ prefix)
  end
end
```